# How to style a <slot> from child component Vue.js 3.x

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am trying to style a p tag that is slotted into a child component using the  tag.

Parent Code

```
<template>
  <BasicButton content="Test 1234" @click="SendMessage('test')" height="10" width="50" />
  <TransparentTopbar />
  <BasicContainer width="90">
    <p class="p-blueish-gray">{{ LorumIpsum() }}</p>
  </BasicContainer>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import Homepage from "./components/home/Homepage.vue";
import TransparentTopbar from "./components/tools/topbar/TransparentTopbar.vue";
import BasicButton from "./components/tools/button/BasicButton.vue";
import BasicContainer from "./components/tools/container/basic_container/BasicContainer.vue"
//import func from "vue-temp/vue-editor-bridge";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Homepage,
    TransparentTopbar,
    BasicButton,
    BasicContainer
  },
  methods: {
    SendMessage: sendMessage,
    LorumIpsum: lorumIpsum
  },
});
```

Child Code

```
<template>
    <div class="light-rounded-container card-margins" :style="container_style">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="./BasicContainer.ts" />
<style scoped src="./BasicContainer.css" />

import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'BasicContainer',
    props: {
        width: {
            type: Number,
            default: 90,
            required: false
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            container_style: {
                width: this.width.toString() + '%'
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {}
});

.light-rounded-container {
    background-color: #242629;
    border-radius: 15px;
    align-self: center;
}

::v-slotted(p) {
    color:red !important;
    width: 1% !important;
    padding-left: 5% !important;
    padding-right: 5% !important;
    padding-top: 25px !important;
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
}
```

The BasicContainer component is the one I am trying to style slotted content on. I would like to style the p tag that I pass to this component in the parent, but I would like to style it from within this child component.

Comment: Just use basic CSS selectors  `.light-rounded-container > p`

Comment: if only that worked, I would be very happy. Unfortunately I tried it already and just confirmed one more time that it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it does.  Is your style tag scoped?

Comment: @StevenB. you are corrent. I did not have my style in a separately defined NON-SCOPED .css file. After moving my styling into their and re structuring my HTML to avoid bleeding the css style into other global scope, it worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@StevenB. you are corrent. I did not have my style in a separately defined NON-SCOPED .css file. After moving my styling into their and re structuring my HTML to avoid bleeding the css style into other global scope, it worked. Much appreciated.